# For $a \in K$, is $N_{L/K}(a) = a^{[L:K]}$ or is it rather $a^{[L:K]_s}$?

Tags: number-theory, field-theory

Let $L/K$ be a field extension of finite degree. For $a \in K$, I have seen in numerous places the norm formula

$$N_{L/K}(a) = a^{[L:K]},$$

where $[L:K]$ is the degree of $L/K$. But when I try to compute it myself I keep getting

$$N_{L/K}(a) = a^{[L:K]_s}$$

where $[L:K]_s$ is the *separable* degree of $L$ over $K$. Am I doing something wrong?

Here's my calculation. Recall that, choosing a finite extension $M/L$ such that $M/L$ and $M/K$ are normal, we have $N_{L/K}(\alpha) = \prod_{\sigma \in Aut_K(M) / Aut_L(M)} \sigma(\alpha)$ for $\alpha \in L$. So for $a \in K$, we have 
$$N_{L/K}(a) = a^{[Aut_K(M): Aut_L(M)]}.$$

Now, it seems to me that because $M/L$ and $M/K$ are normal, we have $[Aut_K(M):Aut_L(M)] = \frac{|Aut_K(M)|}{|Aut_L(M)|} = \frac{[M:K]_s}{[M:L]_s} = [L:K]_s$, not $[L:K]$.

Comment: I say $a^{[L:K]}$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown How does the calculation go?

Comment: The norm of $\alpha\in L$ is the determinant of the $K$-linear map from $L$ to $L$ given by multiplication by $\alpha$. When $\alpha=a\in K$ then that's a scalar map on a vector space of dimension $[L:K]$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Ah... I've been working with the definition $N_{L/K}(\alpha) = \prod_{i: L \to \bar K} i(\alpha)$.  I wonder if a separability hypothesis is needed for these definitions to be equivalent...

Comment: Indeed. In general you should take your formula to the $[L:K]_i$-th power.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thanks. This is frustrating -- I'm reading Neukirch right now and it seems he introduces the norm in Ch I in the context of number fields where separability is automatic, and then later (Ch II) starts using the norm in the context of local fields without commenting on this issue!

Answer (score 1):

With $L/K$ finite not separable and $F/K$ its normal closure, $G = Aut(F/K), H = Aut(F/L)$ then $L = F^H$ and $F^G/K$ is purely inseparable of degree $ [F^G:K] = [L:K]_i=p^n$ and $N_{F^G/K}(b) = b^{p^n}$ and $$N_{L/K}(a) = N_{F^G/K}(N_{F^H/F^G}(a)) = (\prod_{\sigma \in G/H} \sigma(a))^{p^n}$$

The key point is that $F/K$ normal, $G = Aut(F/K)$ implies $F^G/K$ purely inseparable. If it was not then there would be $a \in F^G =  \{ c \in F, \forall g \in G, g(c) = c\}$ whose minimal polynomial $f \in K[x]$ has another root $b$ and we could find an automorphism $\rho \in Aut(F/K), \rho(a) = b$, contradicting that $a \in F^G$. Whence for every $a$ its minimal polynomial is of the form $f(x) = (a-x)^m$ and $gcd(f,f') = 1 \implies m =p^l, p = char(K)$ and $N_{F^G/K}(c) = c^{p^n}$.